# How do I convert array of Objects from an API Response into an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, api, object

I have an a JSON response from an API service below

```
data = [{
                id: 'event-1',
                title: 'All Day Event',
                start: '-01T14:30:00',
                end: '-02T14:30:00',
                className: "bg-danger",
                description: 'Aenean fermentum quam vel sapien rutrum cursus. Vestibulum imperdiet       finibus odio, nec tincidunt felis facilisis eu. '
            },
               {
                id: 'event-2',
                title: 'kiniko',
                start: '-01T14:30:00',
                end: '-02T14:30:00',
                className: "bg-success",
                description: 'Vestibulum imperdiet finibus odio, '
            },
            .....
];
```

How can i i convert it to only object or extract the object?

example is below

```
convertedObject = {
                id: 'event-1',
                title: 'All Day Event',
                start: '-01T14:30:00',
                end: '-02T14:30:00',
                className: "bg-danger",
                description: 'Aenean fermentum quam vel sapien rutrum cursus. Vestibulum imperdiet finibus odio, nec tincidunt felis facilisis eu. '
            },
                    {
                id: 'event-2',
                title: 'kiniko',
                start: '-01T14:30:00',
                end: '-02T14:30:00',
                className: "bg-success",
                description: 'Vestibulum imperdiet finibus odio, '
            }
            ....
;
```

In the convertedObject variable, the [] array should be gone leaving only the object {}.

Thanks guys!

Comment: So basically you want to create a reference to the object outside of the array? `const object = array[0]`

Comment: @Other Me Yes exactly

Comment: Your expected output is not valid javascript.

Answer (score 2):

The object is simply the first item in the array so you should be able to reference it with a simple `[0]`:

`const object = data[0];`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply access the 0th index of the returned result, which will help you in getting only the object.

```
let data = [{ ...your data }]
let obj = data[0]
```